# UIPopoverController, backgroundColor = clearColor

Tags: iphone, uipopovercontroller, uicolor

I had a UITableView that I replaced with a UIPopoverController.  My UITableView's background was set to clearColor and it showed the custom background through the table.  The table cells also matched the grey tint of my background image.

Now when I use the UIPopovercontroller, with the background set to clearColor, I can see through my UIPopoverController, but the color is the "standard" popover controller color.  The kind of grey/blue tint.  Is there a way to change that?  Thanks.

Comment: are you add a table view controller to the popover or a view controller with a uiatableview inside a uiview? if you use a uitableview inside a uiview, you can set the background of uiview to a nice image (uicolor pattern) or add a uimage view and set the uitableview background to clear color (so you get rid of those shadow stripes of group-style tables)